# iTunes Connect Autoingestion.class doing nothing

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to get the iTunes connect report of an app.
To do so I use the Autoingestion.class that apple provides, and set my username/password in autoingestion.properties. The documentation of apple isn't up to date about the properties file who's now unavoidable.

My problem is that when I execute the command line, no error is shown and nothing happens.

My command line look like this :

```
java Autoingestion autoingestion.properties 8****** Sales Daily Summary 20130701
```

autoingestion.properties contains :

```
userID = xxxx@XXX.com
password = PaSsWoRd
```

What am I missing ?

My output (nothing) :

```
$C:\autoingestion>java Autoingestion autoingestion.properties 8****** Sales Daily Summary 20130701
$C:\autoingestion>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok so I came back to work this morning, did the EXACT same command line, and now it works...My guess is iTunes Connect is having some troubles...

Comment: I have the same error since yesterday.
Suddenly Autoingestion does not show errors but does not return the file on my production environment.
My server is a virtualhost on hetzner. All works ok in my local environment.

Comment: Indeed, the autoingest server seems to be having issues. I also am not receiving any reports since several days. I tried both Apple's Autoingestion.Class (Java) and this [unofficial PHP Class](https://github.com/kmonaghan/itunes-connect-auto-ingest) but both don't return anything, not even for earlier dates.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I get the same header with tzunany's answer.

Comment: I am also getting this error. I don't see how it could be a server issue because it works every time on my dev box, but never works on the production box. Both are running the same JRE version.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. The same code is working on my local environement.

Autoingestion is retrieving data from this itunes url https://reportingitc.apple.com/autoingestion.tft.

In my local machine I can download the data correctly. Here you can see the headers recived:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C661B770C05C723FB06CFD0223D46976; Path=/
< Content-Encoding: agzip
< Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=S_D_85242578_20130923.txt.gz
< filename: S_D_85242578_20130923.txt.gz
< Content-Type: application/a-gzip
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 13:47:48 GMT
```

In my prod environement I get these headers:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 13:52:04 GMT
<
```

So nothing else is returned in the request. (Using same version of curl)

Answer (score 0):

Installing OpenJDK fixed this for me.